# jQuery UI menu placement and keeping menu open until mouseout

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, menu

I am using jQuery UI to create a menu.  I am having a few issues.

- I can't get the menu to open underneath the trigger I created.  (Attach it to the trigger?)
- When the menu is opened it does not stay open while I am selecting items.

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/N3HZt/

and Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>jquery Menu</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $( '#menu' ).hide();

      $( '#menu' ).menu();

      $( '#showHideMenu' ).mouseover(function() {
        $( '#menu' ).show();
      });

      $( '#showHideMenu' ).mouseout(function() {
        $( '#menu' ).delay(2000).hide(0);
      });

      $( '#menu' ).mouseover(function() {
        $( '#menu' ).show();
      });

      $( '#menu' ).mouseout(function() {
        $( '#menu' ).delay(2000).hide(0);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body >
  <table width="96%" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        <a href="#" ><span alt="Home" title="Home" class="ui-icon ui-icon-home" style="display:inline-block"></span></a>

        <span id="showHideMenu" alt="Settings" title="Settings" class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench" style="display:inline-block"></span>
        <ul id="menu" style="position: absolute;z-index:9999;">
          <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Addyston</a></li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Delphi</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a></li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
        </ul>

        <a href="#" ><span alt="Help" title="Help" class="ui-icon ui-icon-help" style="display:inline-block"></span></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <p style="border: 2px solid; height: auto; width: 96%;margin: 0 auto;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu velit varius, ornare tellus a, rutrum diam. Sed lacinia nunc in metus ultrices, iaculis euismod justo porttitor. 
  </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Per the user user3124081 I changed the event action from mouse out to click so it will work better with mobile browsers.  Now just to figure out how to close the menu when anywhere else is clicked.
http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/N3HZt/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Hard to find, Simple to implement.

Adding `return false;` in the click function for `#showHideMenu`. Adding click on document hides the `#menu`.

I don't know why the `#showHideMenu` icon nor the `#menu` itself is considered part of the document hide.

For placement I used the css `right` property on `#menu`.  I would have preferred something that ties the trigger `#showHideMenu` with `#menu` so that if the trigger is moved then `#menu` will also move.  If I find a solution to this I will post a follow up.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/N3HZt/7/

CSS:

```
.menuContent {
    right:      35px;
    position:   absolute;
    z-index:    9999;
    text-align: left;
}

.menuIcon {
    display:    inline-block;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#menu').hide();

  $('#menu').menu();

  $('#showHideMenu').click(function () {
      $('#menu').toggle();
      return false;
  });

  $(document).click(function () {
      $('#menu').hide();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table width="96%" border="1" align="center">
 <tr>
    <td align="right"> 
      <a href="#"><span alt="Home" title="Home" class="ui-icon ui-icon-home menuIcon" ></span></a>
      <span id="showHideMenu" alt="Settings" title="Settings" class="ui-icon ui-icon-wrench menuIcon"></span>
      <ul id="menu" class="menuContent">
            <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ada</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Adamsville</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Addyston</a>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Delphi</a>

                <ul>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Ada</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Salzburg</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Saarland</a>
            </li>
      </ul> 

      <a href="#"><span alt="Help" title="Help" class="ui-icon ui-icon-help menuIcon"></span></a>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p style="border: 2px solid; height: auto; width: 96%;margin: 0 auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean eu velit varius, ornare tellus a, rutrum diam. Sed lacinia nunc in metus ultrices, iaculis euismod justo porttitor.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest implementing a hover function to begin with. Your aim for any site should be always to make sure you can implement it on mobile and tablets. Remember, the only mouse you have on a touch screen is a finger. So try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
 <header>
            <div class="container">

    <nav class="">
        <button type="button" class="btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

    </nav>        
        </header>
```

**JavaScript:**

`$(function(){$(".btn-navbar").click(function(){$("nav").toggleClass("open")})})`;

**CSS:**

```
nav.open ul {
    display: block;
  }
  nav .btn-navbar {
    margin: 9px 0 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
  }
  nav .btn-navbar:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  nav .btn-navbar:active {
    margin-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
  }
  nav .btn-navbar .icon-bar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 3px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 62px;
    width: 190px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    line-height: 1 !important;
    color: #1a85eb !important;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f3f4f6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  nav ul li a.highlight {
    background: #f3f4f6 !important;
  }
  nav ul li .dropdown-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    border: none;
  }
  nav ul li .dropdown-menu a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  nav ul li .dropdown-menu a:hover {
    background: #fff;
  }
  nav ul li .dropdown-menu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I created a jsFiddle for this and I think I'm missing something.  It just creates a clickable button but no action is taken when clicked.  http://jsfiddle.net/djlerman/224my/

Comment: Hmm I'll take a look. Well honestly what you could do is keep what you had for the hover function and just implement an on click java script method instead.